# How can the following assignment be made legal?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, java-8

The following produces a ClassCastException and I cannot ascertain why. I understand that generic arrays are a bit taboo as a result of the invariant vs covariant properties and the fact that generics are not reifable but do not understand why a RuntimeException is generated.

```
   ...
   Integer[] sap = (Integer[]) iterableToArray(path.pathTo(w));
}

private <T> T[] iterableToArray(Iterable<T> it){
   ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
   for(T o : it)
      list.add(o);
   return (T[]) list.toArray();

}
```

Comment: Have you checked JavaDoc for signature of `ArrayList#toArray()`? It returns `Object[]`. You can't cast `Object[]` to `Integer[]`, it has nothing to do with reifiability of generics.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
private static <T> T[] iterableToArray(Iterable<T> it, T[] arrayTemplate){
  ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for(T o : it)
    list.add(o);
  return list.toArray(arrayTemplate);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Integer[] sap = iterableToArray(path.pathTo(w), new Integer[0]);
```

You have to pass a variable with a reified type for `T`, because the method `iterableToArray` needs one to create the array. You need not cast the result of `iterableToArray`, so this usage is type safe.

The variable `arrayTemplate` is there only for passing the type to the method. As the result does not fit in the array of size 0, the method `toArray` makes a new array. This is usually faster than passing an array of the needed size to the method `toArray`. And it is also simpler. So this is the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If iterable is iterable of Integer, and you are using java 8+ then you can use this

```
Iterable<Integer> iterable = Arrays.asList(5, 7, 11, 13, 17);
Integer[] numbers = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast  `Object[]` to `Integer[]`.

As long as you cannot instantiate a generic type array (`new T[]`), you have to provide `IntFunction<T[]> generator` that produces a new array of the desired type and the provided length. See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-).

```
static <T> T[] iterableToArray(Iterable<T> it, IntFunction<T[]> toArrayFunction) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T o : it) {
        list.add(o);
    }
    return list.toArray(toArrayFunction);
}
```

... which shall be simplified to ...

```
static <T> T[] iterableToArray(Iterable<T> it, IntFunction<T[]> toArrayFunction) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false).toArray(toArrayFunction);
}
```

Usage is fairly simple using a method reference:

```
Integer[] sap = (Integer[]) iterableToArray(path.pathTo(w), Integer[]::new);
```